# What is the best way to export a report to PDF in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jspdf, pdfkit, react-pdf

I have a reports app that runs ReactJS on the client-side and NodeJS on the server-side. The app displays a report and contains content like Tables, Graphs, SVGs and more.

I want to export this report to PDF with a proper layout with the click of a button.

What is the best way to achieve this functionality? Please suggest both vectorized and non-vectorized solutions to this problem.

*The image below is my React App and I want to export the red-bordered box to a nicely structured PDF file.*

[image: This is how my React App looks like. I want to export the red bordered box that contains the actual report to a PDF file]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PDF using [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) in this package you can access the browser’s print window pragmatically. Using that print window you can export the pdf.

This is the way that you can do it.

```
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.emulateMediaType('print');

pdf = await page.pdf({printBackground: true,width: `21cm`,height: `${height}px`,pageRanges: '1',});
```

Thanks.